# Python Zeep - List Object has no Attribute _xsd_name

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeep

I'm trying to call a SOAP endpoint using the Zeep library.

The endpoint has the following signature:

```
ExecuteStaticSQLQuery(queryType: ns0:StaticQueries, xmlParameters: {_value_1: ANY}, iRowsAffected: xsd:int) -> ExecuteStaticSQLQueryResult: xsd:int, iRowsAffected: xsd:int
```

I built a function that contains the following logic:

```
INSERT_AUTO_FORWARD_IMPORT = 'INSERT_AUTO_FORWARD_IMPORT_1'

query_parameter = self.client.get_type('ns0:QueryParameter')
db_type = self.client.get_type('ns0:DbType')

table_parameter = query_parameter(ParameterType=db_type('String'), 
                                  ParameterName='@Auto_Forward_Table_Name', 
                                  ParameterValue=auto_forward_table)

any_object = AnyObject(query_parameter, table_parameter)
xml_parameters = {
     '_value_1': any_object
}

soap_envelope = self.service.ExecuteStaticSQLQuery(queryType=INSERT_AUTO_FORWARD_IMPORT, 
                                                   xmlParameters=xml_parameters, 
                                                   iRowsAffected=rows_affected)
```

When I call the function I get the following error:

```
'list' object has no attribute '_xsd_name'
```

I suspect the issue is coming from the `any_object` I build, because I can send a request to the endpoint without the `xmlParameters` argument and I get a response back.

Based on the [Zeep Any Objects Docs](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html#any-objects), I would think I'm correctly constructing the `AnyObject` and implementing the call to the SOAP endpoint.

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you are correctly creating the `AnyObject`.

According to the [Zeep docs you link to](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html#any-objects), you should be calling `get_element`, not `get_type`, to construct the `AnyObject`.

In other words, try replacing the line

```py
query_parameter = self.client.get_type('ns0:QueryParameter')
```

with

```py
query_parameter = self.client.get_element('ns0:QueryParameter')
```